# Characteristic of a ring R divides the number of elements m of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Question: Let $R$ be a ring with $m$ elements. Show that the characteristic of $R$ divides $m$.

No mention has been made as to whether the elements are distinct so we're going to assume it is.

Let $\text{char}(R)=n$.

By hypothesis: $\forall x \in R, n\cdot x=x+\ldots +x=0$.

From here, I'd like to use Lagrange theorem but it seems I'm short of a pertinent step required to bridge this.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by characteristic of R ? Do you mean class equations ?

Comment: The characteristic of a ring R is the least positive additive order n such that for any element (say, x) in R: n.x=0

Comment: By the way, if it is says R has m elements, why do you need to be said that the elements are distinct ? For example the set $\{a,a,a \}$ has one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic of $R$ is $n$, so there exists $x\in R$ with additive order $n$. Apply Lagrange's theorem to the additive subgroup of $R$ generated by $x$.

Comment: It is not a given the unity exists...

Comment: Sir, how can we prove first line of your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $R$ has a unit Let $n$ be the cardinal of $R$. The characteristic is the order of the subgroup of $(R,+)$ generated by $1$ so it divides $n$ by Lagrange theorem.

If $R$ does not have a unit for every $x\in R$, let $n_x$ the order of $x$, $n_x$ divides $n$ by Lagrange theorem,  this implies that the common multiple of $n_x,x\in R$ divides $n$ and this common multiple  is the characteristic.

Comment: It is not a given that the unity exists...